# How to pass custom data to an angular-strap modal

Tags: angular-strap

I am using angular-strap's modal and have built my own template. My issue is that my template has 2 buttons, however, I the text and functionality of these buttons will change. As a result, I would like to pass on that data to the modal before I opened it.

In the documentation it says

```
// Pre-fetch an external template populated with a custom scope
  var myOtherModal = $modal({scope: $scope, template: 'modal/docs/modal.tpl.demo.html'});
```

However, i haven't been able to get it working. Note that I would only like some values passed to the modal scope, not my entire parent $scope (which is what the example seems to do)

Answer (score 6):

It's not as straightforward as in ui-bootstrap but it looks more flexible:

```
// creates new isolated scope
var myNewScope = $scope.$new(true);
// then you can data to your new scope
myNewScope.users = ["User1", "User2", "User3"];
var myOtherModal = $modal({scope: myNewScope, template: 'modal/docs/modal.tpl.demo.html'});
```